# Git creates a file automatically with some log content

Tags: git

Git creates a file with following content , If I delete the file this file gets created automatically. How can I stop git from creating this file ?

`14:44:46.907291 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain' '--ignore-submodules=dirty' '--untracked-files=all'
14:44:46.914295 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'tag'
14:44:46.957826 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain' '--untracked-files=all' '--ignore-submodules=dirty'
14:44:47.148534 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' 'HEAD'
14:44:47.263556 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain' '--untracked-files=all' '--ignore-submodules=dirty'
14:44:47.306590 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'remote' 'show' '-n' 'origin'
14:44:47.345621 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' 'HEAD'
14:44:47.380647 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'config' 'push.default'
14:44:47.426698 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'remote' 'show' '-n' 'origin'
14:44:47.548270 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'config' 'push.default'
14:44:47.849401 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'tag'
14:44:47.850402 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain' '--ignore-submodules=dirty' '--untracked-files=all'
14:44:47.867413 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain' '--untracked-files=all' '--ignore-submodules=dirty'
14:44:47.967491 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' 'HEAD'
14:44:48.068578 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'remote' 'show' '-n' 'origin'
14:44:48.069578 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain' '--untracked-files=all' '--ignore-submodules=dirty'
14:44:48.184670 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' 'HEAD'
ult'`

Comment: I'm not an expert in Git, but this just looks like a harmless log file.  Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: It gets created for each and every repository I understand I can ignore it using .gitignore but I might have changed something which have resulted in creating this file

Comment: Windows or Unix-like OS? My answer addresses Unix-like OSes and it can also be used on Windows if you are using Git through Cygwin or the so-called Git Bash.

Comment: Windows OS , yes you are right running command `env | grep GIT_TRACE` showed me `GIT_TRACE=E:ododgitlog` , I cannot find ~/.profile or bash file location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have created some [environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_debugging) that tell Git to trace its internal workings in a file.

Run `env | grep GIT_TRACE` to identify these variables (they are listed in the documentation listed above) and find the configuration file that sets them.

They are probably set by the scripts executed by your shell when it starts. If your shell is Bash then check `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` and other scripts they read and execute.

Comment: Windows OS , yes you are right running command env | grep GIT_TRACE showed me GIT_TRACE=E:ododgitlog , I cannot find ~/.profile or bash file location

Comment: `bash` replaces `~` with your home directory (you are probably using Git Bash). Try `ls -al ~` in a terminal  to list the files in your home directory.

Comment: I used `unset GIT_TRACE_PACKET GIT_TRACE` to unset the Git trace environment variable which `solved` the issue